# SQL Server Insert Into Select one row at a time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to use

`INSERT INTO [table] 
SELECT [columns] 
FROM [table2] 
WHERE [clause]`

It loads perfectly. There is an error on row (?) so the entire insert is rolled back. I am trying to get this to load before and after the error. Also found TRY...CATCH in SQL to handle these issues.

Now, CURSOR seems like the exact answer but everything I read states that CURSOR should be avoided and is not Best Practice.

Anyone have a better option for my exact situation.

Comment: Do the data types of the corresponding columns match between the tables?

Comment: Is this a one shot fix (IE, you are trying to locate the broken record) or is this a going forward script that can handle finding an error like this?

Comment: What error are you encountering?

Comment: I suspect at least one column has different data types (or different data lengths).  For instance, TableA may have an invalid date in ColumnA, and TableB's ColumnA is a DATETIME... Or TableA may have a ColumnB VARCHAR(64), and TableB's ColumnB is VARCHAR(32).  Just a thought...

Comment: It is going forward. I am taking OCR parsed data and trying to automate the insert process. So there is an opportunity for this to be a regular occurance

Comment: That is exactly what happened. The datatime was in an invalid state from the OCR. So it rolled back. I fixed the issue and it loaded but I will not be monitoring this going forward, it will be automated so SQL needs to address the errors and not rollback all the correct rows.

Comment: See if the `ISDATE` function can help:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx

Comment: Agreed with @DMason... `INSERT INTO...SELECT CASE WHEN ISDATE(COL1)=1 THEN COL1 ELSE GETDATE() END` ?? Or something to that effect... or you can put it in the `WHERE` clause, and only insert those `WHERE ISDATE(COL1)=1` and handle the others elsewhere...

Comment: Note that if the corresponding column data types from TableA and TableB **really** are identical, your problem goes away.

Comment: In the select clause on your insert...you can do some string formatting and converting of data types to ensure that all data coming over fits the definition of the destination table.  If your data is varchar(64) coming into the table, but the destination table has it varchar(32)...then something simple like left(field,32) will trim this down to the first 32 chars.  You'd have to do that for each field where the column definition in table2 was different from table1

Comment: @DMason - I agree with the really identical comment, but the process is pulling from an XML, loading everything to a table. Then converting the varchars to datetime where appropriate, then loading so the time the insert occurs they are identical. I may be able to use the ISDATE() thank you. That was a fantastic suggestion.

Comment: Your statement that cursors are bad practice indicates that you do not understand *why* they are bad practice most of the time. For some situations they are perfectly adequate. Don't blindly apply stuff you read on the internet.